# How to apply an ajax funcion to all elements?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a function that shows a number on a button using ajax and ehn the button's is clicked I disable it.I would like to disable all buttons in a function. I tried it using a class, but it doesn't work.

This is my script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $(':button').on('click', function(event){
            $('#ID').val(this.id);          
            var tmp = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                type: $('#klik').attr("method"),
                url : $('#klik').attr("action"),
                data : $('#klik').serialize(),
                success: function(d){                       
                    $('#' + tmp).val(d);
                    const button = document.getElementById(tmp);
                    button.disabled = true;

                    if (d == 'bomba'){
                        alert('bb');
                        $(function(){
                          $('.gumb').attr('disabled', true);
                        });
                    }
                    //$('.fake').closest('tr').remove();
                    //$('#popup').dialog('close');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Greska')
                }
            });       
        });
    });
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i < 9 ; i++){ 
        var row = document.createElement("tr") 
        for (var j=0; j < 9 ; j++){ 
                var elem = document.createElement('input');
                elem.class = 'gumb';
                elem.type = 'button';
                elem.id = 'r'+i+'s'+j;
                elem.value = '';
                elem.innerHTML = elem.value; 
                docFrag.appendChild(elem); 
            } 
        document.body.appendChild(docFrag); 
        document.body.appendChild(row); 
    } 
</script>
```

It does alert 'bb' but the function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about elements is an array? you can use forEach()
if it’s html elements you can store it in array then use forEach(), but if you’re not editing then i don’t know

forEach(function(//params){//disable})